# How to handle asynchronous file loading with events in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, event-handling

So I am a little confused on how to use events in Python. I have an API for a program I use that recently changed its file loading method to be asynchronous. These files can take a while to load and in the past the file loading method would halt execution until the file was loaded. Now it immediately goes on to the next line but everything fails then because the file isn't actually loaded yet.

This API does provide an event that fires once the file is loaded. However, I can't wrap my head around how I would change my code to work with this new event-driven method.

Essentially I want to load the file, wait until it is actually loaded, and then continue on with the rest of the program. I was thinking it would be something like:

```
import API

fileLoader = API.FileLoader()

fileLoader.LoadFile('path/to/file')

while not fileLoader.OnFileLoaded():
    # do some sort of waiting here?

# continue on with the rest of the code
```

I have been trying to read up on decorators and callbacks and other such things but they all seem to be used mainly in GUI or web development stuff where everything is event based. This is just one step that needs to wait for an event to fire.

I also don't think the OnFileLoaded event really works like that. I don't see any return value from it and from what I can tell it takes an object called a FileLoaded object that contains data about where it was loaded into. My guess would be that you can try to load multiple files in different instances and just work with them as they get loaded in.

Is there some sort of standard pythonic way of dealing with stuff like this?

Update:

Below is what Visual Studio gives for information on the OnFileLoaded event

```
public event API.FileLoader.OnFileLoadedDelegate OnFileLoaded
    Member of API.FileLoader
```

And for the LoadFile method

```
public void LoadFile(string filePath)
    Member of API.FileLoader
```

And then I went to look what this OnFileLoadedDelegate was and I found this

```
public delegate void OnFileLoadedDelegate(API2.Models.FileLoaded fileLoaded)
    Member of API.FileLoader
```

And it had two methods, one called BeginInvoke

```
public virtual System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(API2.Models.FileLoaded fileLoaded, System.AsyncCallback callback, object object)
    Member of API.FileLoader.OnFileLoadedDelegate
```

and one called EndInvoke

```
public virtual void EndInvoke(System.IAsyncResult result)
    Member of API.FileLoader.OnFileLoadedDelegate
```

Finally I found one more method in the FileLoader class called GetAutomationCallbackService

```
protected override API2.IApplicationCallbackService GetAutomationCallbackService()
    Member of API.FileLoader
```

If I go to API2 I see that it also has an inteface (?) named OnFileLoaded

I hope that helps clear this up, I am quite confused how it all fits together.

Comment: There are many ways to do async, including python's own `async` routines. This doesn't look like python `async`. Is it really just `API.LoadFile(...)`? One way this is done with with classes that expect you to make subclasses that override things like `OnFileLoaded`. The api would call this method and your implementation would do what makes sense in your environment. But that is only one of many options. We would need to know more about this API. For instance, if API exposed a class that does OnFileLoaded, then we'd know.

Comment: I updated the question slightly to make it more accurate as you are correct, there are multiple classes in the API and one class has both of these methods along with a few others (although I don't know if OnFileLoaded would actually be considered a method, its the event). I know the API was built in .NET and intended mainly to be consumed by C#. Other than that the documentation is lacking. I know the object that it shows being passed into the OnFileLoaded method is of a different class from a different dll that I also need to import.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
fileLoader = loop.run_until_complete(API.FileLoader())
loop.run_until_complete(fileLoader.LoadFile('path/to/file'))
```

to be sure that you will load the file before the code pass to the next line

Comment: Maybe, but this appears to be a completely different type of async operation.

Comment: Thats just the low-level async module, in theory should work right?, the run_until_complete method makes sure that the future is released before the code continues.

Comment: The API went from blocking to a callback - python's async uses an event loop that it uses to schedule coroutines to continue executing via await and etc... That's not a callback scheme like we see here. Had this API moved to async, it would be a complete rewrite to use it. This is different. I think a different thread does the file load in the background and calls OnFileLoaded. OP would override that method to implement something sane for the program.

Comment: So I tried this and it didn't like me passing the API.FileLoader() class into the run_until_complete. I have more info under the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this API is working the way I think, you would create your own class that overrides OnFileLoaded to do what you want. One option is for this class to have an Event that it sets when it gets the OnFileLoaded event.

```
import API
import threading

class WaitFileLoad(API.FileLoader):

    def __init__(self):
        self._event = threading.Event()
        super().__init__()

    def LoadFile(self, path):
        self._event.clear()
        super().LoadFile(path)

    def wait(self):
        self._event.wait()

    def OnFileLoaded(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("OnFileLoaded", type(self), args, kwargs)
        self._event.set()

fileLoader = WaitFileLoad()
fileLoader.LoadFile('path/to/file')
fileLoader.wait()
# continue on with the rest of the code
```

Comment: So the file loads like normal but now the code just hangs after it loads so I don't think the event is being set? I added some info from what I could glean using Visual Studio and looking at the dll. I don't really understand how it all works together but hopefully it helps.

Comment: And you didn't get the print? That's disappointing. Not sure what is intended with the api then.